# Android GPS null pointer exeception

Tags: android, gps, nullpointerexception

Basically, I don't know if this is Eclipse's problem or my phone's GPS or the my app's code.

The problem: When I try restart my phone and run my app, it crashes on Runtime. The error is NullPointer (no line number is provided). But if I remove the two lines from onCreate() which checks for GPS, and run the app again, it works. Then if I re-add those lines again, the app works. So basically, the code is fine but it crashes the App if it's being run for the first time after phone has been restarted. Here is some relevant code:

**EDIT**

Okay this is what I have done:

```
    if (new LocTools(this).checkGPS() == true) { // new method, checks if Gps is active and returns boolean.
        LatLng ll = new LocTools(this).getMyLocation();
        if (ll != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "LatLng: "+ll, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // ll is NOT null
            //LocTools.goToLocation(map,ll,5,true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Gps error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I commented out the LocTools.goToLocation line and inserted a Toast to see if LatLng was null. Result: it was NOT. Then I uncommented the LocTools.goToLocation, so the code looked like this:

```
        ...
        if (ll != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "LatLng: "+ll, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LocTools.goToLocation(map,ll,5,true);
        }
        ...
```

And ran the app, and it crashed on Runtime - NullPointer! I don't understand why it's doing this. There is NO NullPointer...

Comment: First, check is null. Than do whatever you want.

Comment: Okay the problem lies inside LocTools.getMyLocation() method. I'm trying to see why even though GPS is enabled LocationManager is returning Null for the first time app is run after restart.

Comment: Location from LastkNownLocation might be NULL sometimes. Check for null before calling getlatitude();

Comment: @User See main post for update. I changed my getMyLocation() to see if Location was null. Still no luck

Comment: what is type of Latlng

Comment: Solved, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: LatLng was not NULL. When attempting to move Map Camera to the LatLng position. A NullPointerException was being received. It seemed strange as there was no reasonable explanation:

Solved: I have AsyncTask executed from onCreate(). To resolve the NullPointerExeception, I must include the moveCamera command (in my case, my custom LocTools.goToLocation() method) must be inside a Runnable. Like so:

```
if (new LocTools(this).checkGPS() == true) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            LocTools.goToLocation(map, new LocTools(getBaseContext()).getMyLocation(),5,true);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Return default location instead of null.

```
    public LatLng getMyLocation() {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setTitle("GPS");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.gps);
            builder.setMessage("Please enable GPS satellites then try again")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("GPS settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                       mContext.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();


return new LatLng(mock_lat,mock_lng);

        } else {
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            double lat = l.getLatitude();
            double lng = l.getLongitude();
            return new LatLng(lat,lng);
        }
    }
```

OR

```
 if (new LocTools(this).getMyLocation()!=null) {
        LatLng ll = new LocTools(this).getMyLocation();
        LocTools.goToLocation(map,ll,3,true);
    }
```